# PDF-Creation in Swift: Create New Page Automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, pdf

I want to include the PDF-Creation of a (very long) table in my app.

I used this tutorial, to create a PDF file from a HTML-template: https://www.appcoda.com/pdf-generation-ios/

This works well, however, when I have a very long table (with differently sized rows), I would like to *automatically* start a new page. How is this possible (to detect, if the current PDF-page is full)?

Example: Too many items, no space to print footer and some items are missing

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you find or manage to implement a solution? I'm interested in this as well.

Comment: hey @akdsouza, unfortunately, I have not found a solution so far. Since all the rows had the same height in my project, I could manually start a new page after N rows. However, I would also prefer an automatic solution that works with differently sized rows...

Answer (score 0):

The footer overlap with items due to minimal page height. so fix this with the following code:

In class InvoiceComposer.swift

```
func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {
    let data = NSMutableData()
//UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect.zero, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:612,height:822), nil)// Edit CGRect.zero with CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:612,height:822) makes space for footer
    for i in 0..<printPageRenderer.numberOfPages {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        printPageRenderer.drawPage(at: i, in: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())//Print(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0) for UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    return data
}
```

Result Image
[image]
Happy Coding :)